# Why does some currency symbols appear behind the number?

Tags: html, symbols

I have a sum of money like this:

؋321,000 (AFN)

But the `؋` sign is being rendered behind the number although I put it in front.

Why is that so? And how do I fix this in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`؋` is a symbol of right to left language. so whatever the things you type after that will appear before it.

Comment: Are the prices also written with the symbol behind?

Comment: that's how those languages behave.if you need to try and see type it in the Google search box and see what is happening :)

Comment: Thanks, yes, I get the right to left part, just wonder whether the position of the currency symbol is correct. Or they actually put it 'behind', making it appearing in front.

Comment: Then we have the Scandinavian countries who all write their currency after the value, but still write sentences left-to-right, ex: 100kr, 10,00kr

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian: Is it a reason for downvote? `kr` is not a symbol of right to left language. so it will appear as you type in left to right. once you enter right to left symbol, rest of the sentence follow the same.